# Ubuntu 10.10 unattended grub2 downgrade

Tags: ubuntu, grub, dpkg, grub2

I've got to install a few machines with grub legacy on them due to issues with symantec ghost (ghost is a requirement that can't be dropped). i've got a script that prepares machines, but there's a slight problem: apt-get purge grub-pc comes up with a dialog window that ignores -y --force-yes. how can i get rid of it?

edit: the debconf template is grub-pc/postrm_purge_boot_grub. --force-confdef doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it.

apparently adding

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

solves the problem, which is weird, because it doesn't work for samba installs, where --force-confdef is required.